# What is largest class of functions $C$ such that we know $\#P$ in not contained in $C$-generated $TC^0$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, circuit-complexity, counting-complexity, permanent

In [1] it is stated that

> "It remains an open question as to whether every function in $\#P$ has $TC^0$ circuits (although it is at least known that not all $\#P$ functions have DLogTime-uniform $TC^0$ circuits)."

$TC^0$ circuits generated by DLogTime functions does not contain $\#P$.
We don't know if $TC^0$ circuits generated by arbitrary functions does not contain $\#P$.

Is there anything known about the cases in between these two?
E.g. is it known if $TC^0$ circuits generated by $L$ does not contain $\#P$?

- [1] Agarwal, Allender, and Datta, "On $TC^0$, $AC^0$, and Arithmetic Circuits"

Comment: @Kaveh You can keep your answer. Maybe you can remark it was for an erroneous version.

Comment: I don't think it answers the question, so it is not really an answer. :)

Comment: Well it had some nice details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an (interesting) open problem, as far as I know. Rahul Santhanam and I explicitly mention the problem of proving Permanent is not in LOGSPACE-uniform TC0 in our CCC'13 paper (On Medium-Uniformity and Circuit Lower Bounds).

Comment: More conservatively, one could ask about [DTISP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#dtisp) $\hspace{-0.04 in}\left(\log(n)\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}(\log(\log(n)))^{o(1)}\hspace{-0.02 in},\hspace{-0.02 in}O(\log(n))\right)\hspace{-0.02 in}$-uniformity. $\;\;\:\:$

Comment: @Ricky Demer, that is already known. See for example Chen and Kabanets http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2012/007/download/

Comment: Well, by that paper, POLYLOGTIME is a "class of functions C such that we know #P is not contained in" C-uniform TC0. $\:$ Furthermore, by padding, POLYLOGTIME is larger than DLOGTIME.

Comment: Exactly... So, lower bounds for the uniformity you mentioned above are already known.

Comment: ... and, those lower bounds are not mentioned in your answer. $\;$

Comment: Which section are referring permanent in people.csail.mit.edu/rrw/WeakUniformityCCC.pdf (searching permanent in the document is empty result)?

Comment: Hmm I guess we only mentioned the open problem during the CCC talk, but not in the actual paper :) Sorry about that. I assure you, we were certainly trying to prove it!