# $\mathsf{ACC}^0$ and $\mathsf{TC}^0$ with $\mathsf{Cuniform}$-$\oplus\mathsf{L}$ or $\mathsf{Cuniform}$-$\mathsf{NC}^1$ oracle?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, polynomial-time, logspace, uniformity

$\mathsf{TC}^0$ is a small class with $\oplus\mathsf{L}$ containing it.

Following inclusions are known:
$$\mathsf{Cuniform}\mbox{ -}\mathsf{ACC}^0\subseteq\mathsf{Cuniform}\mbox{ -}\mathsf{TC}^0\subseteq\mathsf{Cuniform}\mbox{ -}\oplus\mathsf{L}\subseteq\mathsf{P}$$
$$\mathsf{PP}\not\subseteq\mathsf{DLOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{ -}\mathsf{TC}^0$$
$$\mathsf{DeterminantMod2}\in\oplus\mathsf{L}$$
where $\mathsf{C}\in\{\mathsf{P},\mathsf{LOGSPACE},\mathsf{DLOGTIME}\}$ and where $\mathsf{DeterminantMod2}$ is the problem of finding determinant of a $0/1$ square matrix modulo $2$.

It is possible $\mathsf{Permanent}$ could reduce to $\mathsf{P}$ by reduction via problems in $\mathsf{DeterminantMod2}$.

So how bad of collapse can we prove to avoid so far?

> Is it known
>
> 1. $$\mathsf{CH}\not\subseteq\mathsf{DLOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{ -}\mathsf{TC}^{{0}^{^{^{\mathsf{C'uniform}\mbox{ -}\oplus\mathsf{L}}}}}$$
>    and/or
> 2. $$\mathsf{CH}\not\subseteq\mathsf{DLOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{ -}\mathsf{ACC}^{{0}^{^{^{\mathsf{C'uniform}\mbox{ -}\mathsf{NC}^1}}}}$$
>    for any $\mathsf{C'}\in\{\mathsf{P},\mathsf{LOGSPACE},\mathsf{DLOGTIME}\}$?

In other words is it known there cannot be a $\mathsf{DLOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{ -}\mathsf{ACC}^0$ algorithm utilizing $\mathsf{DLOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{ -}\mathsf{NC}^1$ oracle which computes the permanent?

It is known http://cjtcs.cs.uchicago.edu/articles/1999/7/contents.html provides
$$\mathsf{PP}\not\subseteq\mathsf{DLOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{ -}\mathsf{TC}^{{0}}.$$

It is unknown if
$$\mathsf{PP}\not\subseteq\mathsf{LOGSPACEuniform}\mbox{ -}\mathsf{TC}^{{0}}$$
holds ([What is largest class of functions $C$ such that we know $\#P$ in not contained in $C$-generated $TC^0$?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32198/what-is-largest-class-of-functions-c-such-that-we-know-p-in-not-contained)).

Possibility of 2. is the deeper collapse.

**Update** The comments below indicate following collapse is not ruled out:
$$\mathsf{CH}\subseteq\mathsf{LOGSPACEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{TC}^0\subseteq\mathsf{LOGSPACEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{ACC}^0.$$

Comment: Any way I look at it, DLOGTIME-uniform $\mathrm{TC}^0$ with a $C'$-uniform $\oplus L$ (whatever that is supposed to mean; normally, $\oplus L$ is already a uniform class) oracle equals just $C'$-uniform $\oplus L$, and likewise, DLOGTIME-uniform $\mathrm{ACC}^0$ with a $C'$-uniform $\mathrm{NC}^1$ oracle equals $C'$-uniform $\mathrm{NC}^1$. Thus, no such thing has been proven. We don’t even know that PP is not included in DLOGTIME-uniform $\mathrm{NC}^1$.

Comment: $ACC$ is similar to ModPH and TC similar to CH. Perhaps Allender's DLOGTIME uniform TC0 not containing PP is time and space hierarchy in disguise? Perhaps similar strategy works to separate DLOGTIME uniform ACC from ModPH?

Comment: There is no disguise; this is a transparent application of the time hierarchy theorem coupled with a padding argument.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Why Allender's proof fails for separating the class $\mathsf{PP}$ and either of the classes $\mathsf{LOGSPACEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{TC}^0$ or $\mathsf{Puniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{TC}^0$ but works for separating the class $\mathsf{PP}$ and the class $\mathsf{DLOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{TC}^0$? Is there something about $\mathsf{LOGSPACEuniform}$ model?

Comment: Why don't you read the proof? The point is that CH is the exponentially scaled up version of DLOGTIME-uniform TC^0, not of any less uniform class.

Comment: I see might I ask if there is an exponentially scaled up version of $\mathsf{Cuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{TC}^0$ class where $\mathsf{C}\in\{\mathsf{LOGSPACE},\mathsf{P}\}$? Would it be similar $\mathsf{PSPACEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{CH}$ or $\mathsf{EXPuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{CH}$ and the $\mathsf{CH}$ which $\mathsf{DLOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{TC}^0$ scales be $\mathsf{Puniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{CH}$ which is the $\mathsf{CH}$ Allender's separation proof refers to?

Comment: I don’t know. It would be quite messy to define. First, LOGSPACE-uniform (P-uniform) TC^0 is, in other words, uniform TC^0 with a polynomial-size LOGSPACE-computable (P-computable, resp.) advice. The exponential version of that, that would make the padding argument work, would be CH with PSPACE-computable (EXP-computable, resp.) exponential-size advice string (accessed by the CH algorithm in a similar way as an oracle). However, as stated, this is not a useful model, as it is too strong: it simply coincides with PSPACE (EXP, resp.), as the advice string may just include the whole truth table.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think it clarifies a lot and no wonder no one has been smart enough to separate $\mathsf{LOGSPACEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{TC}^0$ and $\mathsf{PP}$ or brave enough to claim these are identical. So the interesting problem here is if $\mathsf{DLOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{NC}^1\subseteq\mathsf{LOGSPACEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{TC}^0$?

Comment: It is not out of the unknown if a 'typical' $\mathsf{NC}^1$ polynomial sized program can be unraveled to a polynomial sized constant depth program having majority gates (the program itself might require $\mathsf{LOGSPACE}$ to construct which is not out of the question since no one knows if $\mathsf{SAT}\not\in\mathsf{TISP}\Big(O\Big(\frac{n^2}{\log n}\Big)\mbox{ time},O(\log n)\mbox{ space}\Big)$). It agrees to $\mathsf{TISP}\Big(\mathsf{poly}(n)\mbox{ time},O(\mathsf{polylog}(n))\mbox{ space}\Big)\not\subseteq\mathsf{DLOGTIME}$ and $\mathsf{P}\not\subseteq\mathsf{DLOGTIME}$).

Comment: $$\mathsf{LOGSPACEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{NC}^1\not\subseteq\mathsf{LOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{TC}^0$$ are among the smallest 'difficult' unknown (but extremely helpful (the possibility of non-inclusion is valid under extreme collapse of $\mathsf{CH}$ to $\mathsf{LOGSPACEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{TC}^0$ happens (difficult because proof exists under extreme situations alone is possible))) while

$$\mathsf{LOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{NC}^1\not\subseteq\mathsf{LOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{TC}^0\not\subseteq\mathsf{LOGTIMEuniform}\mbox{-}\mathsf{ACC}^0$$
is probably 'easier'.